# Avoiding over-fitting in Gradient Boosted tree models when multiple sequential observations share the same label

Tags: boosting, overfitting, lightgbm

I am trying to train a Multi-class classification model where every `K` minutes I receive a set of features `x` and use the set to predict an outcome `y`, the values of the features in `x` change partially between to subsequent predictions while some of the features remain constant. Therefore, my in my training set I have, for a single label `y_i` multiple rows of features, `x_i1,...,x_in` that share some of the features and all have the same label `y_i`. What are good methods that I could apply to both utilize the data that I have while avoiding overfitting ?